# Place a sidebarPanel on the page without scrolling

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following snippet of code:

```
sidebarPanel(
    selectizeInput(
        "s1",
        "Select s1",
        choices = c('A', 'B'),
        multiple = FALSE
    ),
    radioButtons(
        "r1",
        "Select r1",
        choices = c("A", "B", "C")
    ),
    radioButtons(
        "r2",
        "Select r2",
        choices = c("P", "R")
    ),
    selectizeInput(
        "s3",
        "Select s3",
        choices = c('C', 'D'),
        multiple = FALSE
    ),
    selectizeInput(
        "s4",
        "Select s4",
        choices = c('A', 'B'),
        multiple = TRUE
    ),
    selectizeInput(
        "s5",
        "Select s5",
        choices = c('A', 'B'),
        multiple = FALSE
    ),
    selectizeInput(
        "s6",
        "Select s6",
        choices = c('A', 'B'),
        multiple = TRUE
    ),
    selectizeInput(
        "s7",
        "Select s7",
        choices = c('A', 'B'),
        multiple = FALSE
    ),
    selectizeInput(
        "s8",
        "Select s8",
        choices = c('A', 'B'),
        multiple = TRUE
    ),
    actionButton(
        "b1",
        "Enter"
    )
)
```

Since there are so many inputs, when I start the application the whole sidebarPanel doesn't fit on the page and the scrolling of the page is activated. Is there a way to make the sidebarPanel smaller (for example by decreasing the font size, or putting the radioButtons options all in one line or something more elegant) so that scrolling is no longer needed?

Comment: You can save a tiny bit of space by showing the radio buttons inline `radioButtons(inline = TRUE)`. Other than that you can change your theme to one that has a smaller font and uses less space between element.

Comment: Alternatively, you can let that section scroll while the rest of the page stays in view. To do that, you can use something like this `sidebarPanel(style = "height:400px; overflow-y:scroll", ... )`

Comment: I would use a scrollbar for the sidebar; see <https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/shinySidebarScrollbar.html>.